# Removing value from range

Tags: list, scala

I have the following case class:

```
case class objRanges(rangeVals:List[rangeNums])
```

where rangeNums represents a range of values and is also a case class:

```
case class rangeNums(lowValue:Int, highValue:Int)
```

I would like to implement a subtraction method for objRanges, one with the following signature:

```
def -(numberRemove:Int): objRanges = {
```

The number would then be removed from all the ranges in the list rangeVals, splitting rangeNums that contain the number into two rangeNums (one from lowValue to n-1 and another from n+1 to highValue). Would this be easier to implement using a for comprehension or foldLeft?

For example, rangeVals currently holds the elements:

```
[(1,3),(5,10)]
```

Calling the - method with 7 as a parameter should return a new instance of objRanges with the elements:

```
[(1,3),(5,6),(8,10)]
```

While subtracting an element which is the lower bound of a range should just increase the lower bound by one, so subtracting 5 in the rangeVals should return:

```
[(1,3),(6,10)]
```

The same applies for the upper bound. If rangeVals currently holds:

```
[(1,3),(5,7)]
```

Then removing 7 should return

```
[(1,3),(5,6)]
```

The last boundary case would be where there is only one number in a range, and that number is to be deleted. For example, if RangeVals currently holds:

```
[(1,3),(7,7)]
```

Removing 7 should just remove the entire range, returning a new instance with rangeVals equal to:

```
[(1,3)]
```

And how would the solution change if I was looking instead to remove all numbers in the ranges less than numberRemove?

Comment: I think your question is simple to implement, yet hard to understand ;). Do you want to split a list in 2 lists based on a range condition? In that case the signature of the minus method is wrong. It should return a pair of lists.

Comment: I don't understand the combination of "The number would then be removed from all the ranges in the list rangeVals, splitting lists that contain the number into two lists". Subtracting a number would be a `map` operation, filtering out `rangeNums` would be a `filter` and splitting ... would be `span`. It's not clear to me which one you want

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, let's say rangeVals contains an element with parameters (0,10); if I pass 5 into the function as the number I want to remove, then rangeVals should contain (0,4) and (6,10) as output. Hence, the new objRanges which is outputted by the subtraction method will return these two rangeNums elements.

Comment: Ok I get it now :) 1 sec

Comment: Could you provide sample data - 2 lists - one as before the operation and one after minus is applied

Comment: that will clarify boundary conditions. for example (1, 3) - 2 ==? (1, 3) or _ ==? (1, 2) :: (2, 3) or something else. Also when n is less than lower bound. ;)

Comment: I've added boundary condition examples.

Comment: one more case: [(1,3),(5,7)], remove 7 - what's the result? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Using **map**:

   ```
   case class RangeNums(lowValue: Int, highValue: Int)

   case class ObjRanges(rangeVals: List[RangeNums]) {
     def -(n: Int): ObjRanges = {
       val res = rangeVals.map {
         case e @ RangeNums(l, h) =>
           if (n > l && n < h) RangeNums(l, n - 1) :: RangeNums(n + 1, h) :: Nil
           else if (n == l) RangeNums(l + 1, h) :: Nil
           else if (n == h) Nil
           else e :: Nil
       }.flatten
       ObjRanges(res)
     }
   }
   ```

   test with REPL:

   ```
   scala> val l = RangeNums(0, 10) :: RangeNums(1, 3) :: Nil
   l: List[RangeNums] = List(RangeNums(0,10), RangeNums(1,3))

   scala>  val r = ObjRanges(l)
   r: ObjRanges = ObjRanges(List(RangeNums(0,10), RangeNums(1,3)))

   scala> r - 5
   res0: ObjRanges = ObjRanges(List(RangeNums(0,4), RangeNums(6,10), RangeNums(1,3)))

   scala> r - 2
   res1: ObjRanges = ObjRanges(List(RangeNums(0,1), RangeNums(3,10), RangeNums(1,1), RangeNums(3,3)))

   scala> r - 10
   res2: ObjRanges = ObjRanges(List(RangeNums(1,3)))

   scala> r - 0
   res3: ObjRanges = ObjRanges(List(RangeNums(1,10), RangeNums(1,3)))
   ```
2. A **tailrec** solution:

   ```
   import scala.annotation.tailrec

   case class ObjRanges(rangeVals: List[RangeNums]) {
     def -(n: Int): ObjRanges = {
       @tailrec
       def minRec(n: Int, rem: List[RangeNums], accu: List[RangeNums]): List[RangeNums] =
         rem match {
           case (e @ RangeNums(l, h)) :: t =>
             val tmpRes =
               if (n > l && n < h) RangeNums(n + 1, h) :: RangeNums(l, n - 1) :: accu
               else if (n == l) RangeNums(l + 1, h) :: accu
               else if (n == h) accu
               else e :: accu
             minRec(n, t, tmpRes)
           case Nil =>
             accu
         }
       ObjRanges(minRec(n, rangeVals, Nil).reverse)
     }
   }
   ```
3. Using **fold**:

   ```
   case class ObjRanges(rangeVals: List[RangeNums]) {
      def -(n: Int): ObjRanges = {
        def minF(accu: List[RangeNums], e: RangeNums) = {
          val l = e.lowValue
          val h = e.highValue
          if (n > l && n < h) RangeNums(n + 1, h) :: RangeNums(l, n - 1) :: accu
          else if (n == l) RangeNums(l + 1, h) :: accu
          else if (n == h) accu
          else e :: accu
        }
        val res = (List[RangeNums]() /: rangeVals)((accu, e) => minF(accu, e))
        ObjRanges(res.reverse)
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Why does your case statement check if n > l + 1? Shouldn't checking if n > l suffice? Also, would this cover cases where n is the lowest value in the range? In those cases, the new range would just be RangeNums(n+1, l)

Comment: yep I was not very clear on the boundary conditions. I made it such that n must be greater than l by 2 such that interval could be split into non-overlapping segments - but it's easy to change to whatever requirements are.

Comment: Okay, last thing I don't understand is why you state e :: Nil on the last case statement. Why isn't it just case e => e ?

Comment: because I have to create a list instead of a single value in the previous case I have to have the same in the second case to comply with the external type of a list. I flatten this afterwards. Technically I could pattern match later and flatten in some other way, but this is just easier.

Comment: because I have to create a list instead of a single value in the previous case I have to have the same type in the second case to comply with the external type of a list List[List[RangeNums]]. I flatten this afterwards. Technically I could pattern match List[Product] later and flatten in some other way, but this is just easier.

Comment: @user1553248 I hope I got all the conditions right. In any case it does not matter - the main logic is there so you can adjust accordingly if needed.